# Store a pointer to a boolean value in a tuple

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I have something like this in my project:

```
struct buttonFlag {
    var flag: Bool
    var button: UIButton
}

var bool1: Bool = false
var bool2: Bool = false
var bool3: Bool = false

var obj1: UIButton = UIButton()
var obj2: UIButton = UIButton()
var obj3: UIButton = UIButton()

let buttonFlags: buttonFlag = [buttonFlag(bool1, obj1), buttonFlag(bool2, obj2), buttonFlag(bool3, obj3)]
```

Instead of handling the values boo1 and flag separated I want the value of flag to be some kind go reference to the value of the boolean values(bool1..3).
Is there any memory efficient way to do this ?

Comment: You're question is really unclear. Can you please add detail?

Comment: A pointer ... in Swift? Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Can you post the code you have now and point out where you think the issue is?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to  declare an array of structs (which contains the buttons and booleans as members) rather than using tuples.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a dictionary of `[UIButton:Bool]`?

Comment: No, this wouldn't change anything. I still would habe to Update bool and flag

Comment: What I am suggesting is that the separate `bool1`, `bool2`, `bool3` are unnecessary. To do what you want, you will need to replace those bools with an object, such as NSNumber wrapping a bool, but simply using a dictionary is easier

Comment: @Raoul What do these button flags do?

Comment: They determine whether a button has been clicked. My idea was to use the value of bool im different contextes, in this case I need a strict connection between the boolean and the button. In an other case I just need the value of the bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want an instance-unique boolean flag associated with each instance of `UIButton`, you could simply subclass the latter, adding a single `Bool` property to the derived class.

```
class MyUIButton: UIButton {
    var flag: Bool = false
}
```

You would treat instances of you custom subclass `MyUIButton` just the way you'd treat instances of its parent class, with the addition that you now have access to `flag` property for each button instance.

Contrived example usage:

```
let btn1 = MyUIButton()
let btn2 = MyUIButton()
let btn3 = MyUIButton()

let buttons = [btn1, btn2, btn3]

btn1.flag = true
btn3.flag = true

for btn in buttons where btn.flag {
    // ... do something with btn1 and btn3
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem because I still would have to change the value of two variables.

Comment: @Raoul I might misunderstand what your want: but no matter how your approach is, if you want to know whether a button has been clicked or not (and store this knowledge in some `bool` instance), you'd need at the very least a property tied to that instance of the button, and/or an action tied triggering some target in the case of some event for the button (e.g. clicked). Given this, it's an easy matter to set a single property of the instance of the button that triggers these events.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I rethought my approach and came to the conclusion that it might be more reasonable and easier to use a subclass of UIButton to store the flag.